# Entity Query Condition for the referenced entity's type

Tags: 8, entities, taxonomy-terms, database

According to the [documentation for the condition() function](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Entity%21Query%21QueryInterface.php/function/QueryInterface%3A%3Acondition/8.2.x), you can append columns to a field name, but I haven't found a way to make a condition on the referenced entity's type.

```
// Something like this?
$query->andConditionGroup()->condition($referenceFieldName, $someId)
     ->condition("$fieldName.entity:type", ['character', 'movie'], 'IN')
```

Let's say with the above I am querying for `articles` that have a reference to the ID in `$someId` *and* that reference is to a content type of either `character` or `movie`. Is something like this possible with `entityQuery`?

**Background**: I'm using the [Dynamic Entity Reference](https://www.drupal.org/project/dynamic_entity_reference) module, which allows me to make a reference field that can point to either a taxonomy term or a piece of content. I want to query for references to content in that field, but am concerned that there could be an ID overlap. That is, a taxonomy term and `character` for example that both have the ID 123. If I am searching for the ID 123, I would only want `articles` that have references to the `characters` or `movies` with the ID 123, not any taxonomy terms with the ID 123.

Answer (score 1):

since the reference field is using DER, you can use $fieldName.target_type for finding the referenced entity's type.

Comment: While it doesn't throw an error about `target_type`, it also doesn't seem to match anything, either. For example if I use `$someId` that points to a `movie` content, it doesn't match `target_type` set to `movie`. Where is the documentation where you found this column name?

Comment: Seems like the only values for `target_type` that work are "node" or "target_type"

Comment: target_id will help to separate out taxonomy and nodes. You can exclude taxonomy terms with this.  will $fieldName.entity:content-type:name work for you?

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. That  format looks like what I need, but it appears to be invalid. The error: `The "content_type:name" entity type does not exist.` Pretty much anything I put after `$fieldName.entity:` gives a similar error. According to the docs, `entity` is the actual entity being referenced, correct?